# what is COLUMN_POSITION in ALL_IND_EXPRESSIONS

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

What is the work of `COLUMN_POSITION` in `ALL_IND_EXPRESSIONS` (Oracle DB).

The values it is returning [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGBh6.png)

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/ALL_IND_EXPRESSIONS.html#GUID-E34E8770-4BCE-47A8-B91A-6BF82889E0C0)  "*Position of the column or attribute within the index*"

Answer (score 3):

When you create a function-based index (that's the "expression" in the view name), `column_position` says which position takes that expression. It is *usually* 1, unless you created a **composite** index; as it consists of two or more columns (expressions), position differs.

For example:

```
SQL> create table test
  2  (id    number,
  3   name  varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> create index i1_test on test (id, substr(name, 1, 2));
                                   --  ------------------
                                   ^        ^
                                   |        |
                                   |        expression is on position 2 in that index 
                                   |
                                   ID is on position 1 in that index                         


Index created.

SQL> select index_name, column_expression, column_position
  2  from all_ind_expressions where table_name = 'TEST';

INDEX_NAME                     COLUMN_EXPRESSION                   COLUMN_POSITION
------------------------------ ----------------------------------- ---------------
I1_TEST                        SUBSTR("NAME",1,2)                                2

SQL>
```

---

It is similar to `USER_IND_COLUMNS`:

```
SQL> select index_name, column_name, column_position
  2  from user_ind_columns where table_name = 'TEST';

INDEX_NAME                     COLUMN_NAME          COLUMN_POSITION
------------------------------ -------------------- ---------------
I1_TEST                        ID                                 1
I1_TEST                        SYS_NC00003$                       2

SQL>
```